# Unable to take screenshot in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I am taking the screenshot of this screen:

[image]

but everytime it gives me the following exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:49644/session/bc1237c6e7484d4c9686555254d3ec70/screenshot
>   timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request
>   was aborted: The operation has timed out. at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo
>   requestInfo) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo
>   requestInfo) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot() at
>   specflowPjt.Hooks.TakeScreenshot()

I am getting the above exception at AddScreenshot() method of selenium.

The code i am using works fine everywhere, but giving exception only at this place. May someone please tell me what could be possible reasons behind this & finally how to take the screenshot of this screen.

**Few pointers that may help you resolving this:**

1. The screen which I am trying to capture is in **loading state**. (can we capture the screen which is in the loading state?)
2. My website is very slow.
3. I am working on remote machine.

Any help would be greatly regarded. Thanks

Comment: Please add your code and tell us what programming language you are using (C# right?).

Answer (score 0):

the probable reason is in -

> 3. I am working on remote machine.

I would suggest to write your own method for screenshooting or take this:

```
 public void make_screenshot(String filename){

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
       try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("test-output\\" +filename +".png").getAbsoluteFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Maybe this will work and u will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Remote machine - we had same difficulties here when testing selenium on remote machine

Regarding taking screenshots issue. There are generally three steps which you have to do:

**Step1:**

Convert web driver object to TakeScreenshot

```
TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)webdriver);
```

**Step2:**

Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file

```
File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

**Step 3:**

Copy file to desiced location:

For more information see link: [How to take Screenshot - Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/take-screenshot-selenium-webdriver.html)

There is already a discussion here: [How to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

But it would be nice to insert your code here. Not just the error message. Because from this point, maybe you should also insert an wait Command (see: [ToolsQA](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/) ) because your error message is saying that it is getting a timeout after 60 seconds...

Hope the links help in your case. Happy testing!